# Deleting all files and directories from desktop except .lnk

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Im trying to write a script for keep clear my desktop. I want to delete all files and directories except the shortcuts.I use Windows 10. My batch code is the following:

```
@echo off
COLOR 0E
cd "C:/Users/DA/Desktop"
FORFILES /S /C "if @ext!=lnk del /F /Q /S"
rd /S /Q "."
pause
exit
```

Maybe it is a dumb error, but Im a newbie in Windows command line. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about folders located on your desktop - do you want to remove them all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

1. You must precede the command line after the `/C` switch of `forfiles` with `cmd /C`, because you are using internal console commands (`if`, `del`). If you omit `cmd /C`, `forfiles` tries to find a program file named `if`, which does not exist.
2. There is no comparison operator `!=` for the `if` statement. You mean *not equal*, so you need to state `if not <expression1>==<expression2>` instead.
3. The `@ext` variable expands to the file extension enclosed in quotation marks, so you need to state them around `lnk` also. Since the `""` are in the quoted command line behind `forfiles` `/C`, you need to escape them like `\"` in order to establish literal `"` characters.
4. You forgot to specify what to delete at the `del` command.
5. The switches `/S` of `forfiles` and also `del` mean to process also items in sub-directories, but I assume you do not want that, because you want to clean up your `Desktop` directory.
6. There is the `rd` command, so I assume you want to remove any directories from the `Desktop` either. However, `rd /S /Q "."` tries to remove the entire `Desktop` directory (which will fail as your batch file changes to that directory by `cd`). I would put the `rd` command into the `forfiles` command line as well, because there is the possibility to check whether or not the currently iterated item is a file or a directory (`forfiles` features the `@isdir` variable for that purpose).
7. The `cd` command works only if you are running the batch file from the same drive where the `Desktop` directory is located (unless you provide the `/D` switch). I would go for the `pushd` command, which changes to the `Desktop` directory temporarily, until a `popd` command is there.
8. Instead of hard-coding the location of the `Desktop` directory, I would use the built-in environment variable `%USERPROFILE%`, which points to the user profile directory of the currently logged on user, where the `Desktop` directory is located in.
9. The `exit` command without the `/B` switch does not only end the batch file, it also terminates the command interpreter instance the batch file is running in. This does not matter when you run the batch file by double-clicking, but it does matter when you execute it within command prompt.

Here is the corrected and improved code:

```dos
@echo off
title Clean Up Desktop & rem // (this is the window title, just for fun)
color 0E
pushd "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop" || exit /B 1 & rem // (the command after `||` runs if `pushd` fails, when the dir. is not found)
rem /* Here you can see how to distinguish between files and directories;
rem    files are deleted with `del`, directories are removed with `rd`.
rem    The upper-case `ECHO`s are there for testing purposes only;
rem    remove them as soon as you actually want to delete any items: */
forfiles /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE (if /I not @ext==\"lnk\" ECHO del /F /Q @relpath) else ECHO rd /S /Q @relpath"
pause
popd & rem // (this restores the previous working directory)
exit /B & rem // (this quits the batch file only; not necessary at the end of the script)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that :

```
@echo off
COLOR 0E
CD /D "%userprofile%\Desktop"
Rem To delete folders
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Dir /b /AD ^| find /v "lnk"') do echo rd /S /Q "%%a"
pause
Rem To Delete files
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Dir /b ^| find /v "lnk"') do echo del /F /Q /S "%%a"
pause
exit
```

**NB:** When your execution is OK, just get rid of `echo` command

Comment: If any of the items on the Desktop has got `lnk` anywhere in their names, they are not going to be deleted by your script; I would add the `/A-D` option to the second `Dir` command line to match files only (although there should not be any dir. left); and I would remove the (superfluous) `/S` switch from the `del` command...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `for` and `if` commands to accomplish this:

```
@echo off
COLOR 0E
cd C:/Users/DA/Desktop
for /d %x in (*) do @rd /s /q "%x"
for %i in (*) do if not %i == *.lnk del "%i"
pause
```

Pretty simple and works great.
Make sure that %i and %x are in "".